# Adding tags to database values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get some values from the database and i want to split it and add html tag into it.

```
$sql = "SELECT
            ip_adres,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nickname2 ORDER BY nickname2) nickname
        FROM
            users
        GROUP BY ip_adres
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

foreach($users as $u){
    $nick = $u['nickname'];
    $ip = $u['ip_adres'];
    echo "$nick $ip";
}
```

`$nick` output is like `value1,value2` now i want to add to both values a `a href` so output must be like 
`<a href=test.php?url=value>value1</a>, <a href=test.php?url=value2>value2</a>` so every nickname will be clickable and href to the nickname page how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try

```
<?php

if($s = $db->query('SELECT
            ip_adres,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nickname2 ORDER BY nickname2) namen
        FROM
                users
        GROUP BY ip_adres
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1')) {
    while ($row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        $c = '';
        $nicks = explode(',', $row['namen']);
        foreach($nicks as $nick) {
            echo "
            $c <a href=$nick>$nick</a> 
            ";
            $c = ', ';
        }
        echo ' IP-Adres (' . $row['ip_adres'] . ')<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
foreach($users as $u){
    $nick = $u['nickname'];
    $ip = $u['ip_adres'];
    echo "<a href='test.php?url=".$nick."'>value1</a>";
    echo "<a href='test.php?url=".$ip."'>value2</a>";
}
```

Alternatively, this will work too:

```
foreach($users as $u){
    $nick = $u['nickname'];
    $ip = $u['ip_adres'];
    echo "<a href='test.php?url=$nick'>value1</a>";
    echo "<a href='test.php?url=$ip'>value2</a>";
}
```

Comment: yes i know this but the $nick variable returns `value,value`
So if i use your suggestion it wil output like <a href=test.php?url=value1,value2>value1,value2</a>